How to compare two actions in a stochastic policy in reinforcement learning?
I am working on comparing actions $a_t$ and $a_{t+1}$ from a stochastic policy $\pi$. However, the policy outputs for $a_t$ is ($\mu_t, \sigma_t$) and for $a_{t+1}$ is ($\mu_{t+1}, \sigma_{t+1}$) values:
$\mu_t, \sigma_t = \pi(s_t)$
$\mu_{t+1}, \sigma_{t+1} = \pi(s_{t+1})$
I have considered three options:

Sampling from the distributions: I can define distributions $P = \text{Normal}(\mu_t, \sigma_t)$ and $Q = \text{Normal}(\mu_{t+1}, \sigma_{t+1})$, then sample actions $a_t = P.\text{sample}()$ and $a_{t+1} = Q.\text{sample}()$. Now I can perform L2-Norm between two actions. However, this approach gives different action values in each sampling, especially during early learning stages, which might not provide meaningful results.

KL divergence: I could calculate the KL divergence between $P$ and $Q$ as a measure of comparison between actions. However, I noticed that both KL(P||Q) and KL(Q||P) are equal and larger than zero, KL(P||Q) = KL(Q||P) > 0 ,which seems not correct. Is this scenario possible?

L2-Norm between means: Another option is to simply compute the L2-Norm between $\mu_t$ and $\mu_{t+1}$. However, I suspect that this might oversimplify the comparison.


I would appreciate any insights on the correctness of these approaches or suggestions for an alternative method.
Thank you in advance!
